# Consulta MySQL desde C# devuelve InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017

Gracias a los usuarios consegui establecer la conexión a mi database MySQL desde C#, pero ahora me surgió otro problema. Yo simplemente quiero obtener un DataSet donde poder despues leer los datos, pero en el momento en que la función acaba, me devuelve siempre InvalidOperationException.

Todas las variables están correctamente inicializadas, y conexionn es la String de conexion. Artists es el nombre de una de las tablas y albums es el de la otra. Cualquier información extra necesaria no dudéis en preguntarme.

Muchísimas gracias a los que se molesten en leer mi pregunta, y más aún a los que contesten!

```
private void creaDataset()
    {
        conexion = new MySqlConnection(conexionn);
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            daArtists = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT*FROM ARTISTS", conexionn);
            daArtists = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT*FROM ALBUMS", conexionn);
            daArtists.Fill(ds, "Artists");
            daAlbums.Fill(ds, "Albums");
        }
        finally
        {

            conexion.Close(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: solo eso obtienes un InvalidOperationException, no hay nada en el message de esa excption que aporte algo mas de dato

Comment: porque asignas dos MySqlDataAdapter a la misma variable ? eso esta raro, sabes que una instancia pisa la anterior, no?

Comment: Buf eso fue el copiapega de una a otro, me confundi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias intentar algo como esto

```
private DataSet creaDataset()
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    using(MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(conexionn))
    {
        conexion.Open();

        var daArtists = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ARTISTS", conexion);
        daArtists.Fill(ds, "Artists");

        var daAlbums = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ALBUMS", conexion);
        daAlbums.Fill(ds, "Albums");
    }
    return ds;
}
```

remarco algunos puntos

- cuando definas el `select * from` deja una separacion entre el asterisco y las palabras
- define diferente nombre de variable para los dataadapter
- define las variables de forma local y no global
- cuando asignas la conexion que sea el objeto `conexion` y no el `conexionn`, recomendaria que pongas variables algo distinta en su nombre como ser cambiar `conexionn` por `connexionString` o algo asi

Comment: Te vas a reir pero lo que fallaba era ese copiapega, al no dar valor a daAlbums, se colapsaba.

Answer (score 0):

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
private void creaDataset()
{
    conexion = new MySqlConnection(conexionn);
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT*FROM ARTISTS", conexion);
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);
        adaptador.Fill(daArtists);

        comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT*FROM ALBUMS", conexion);
        adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);
        adaptador.Fill(daAlbums);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```